# 1-Year "Skills and Talent" France Visa

Tags: france

I am American and have a PhD in computer science. I would like move to France for 1 year to improve my French and work on a tech-scientific project, completely self-funded.

Is the "Skill and Talent" (Carte Compétences & Talents) the best visa for me? If so, how difficult is it to prove the project contributes to France's scientific goals and get the visa request approved?

Comment: The PhD is a good starting point but those permits are very difficult to get. The list of documents required to apply will give you a first idea. They issue about 200-300 of these each year, which is not many. Also, "compétences et talents" permits are being phased out and replaced by something called "passeport talent", not sure how much of a difference it will make.